# ¿Como eliminar dinamicamente un UserControl en c# .net desde el form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un `UserControl` que se agrega dinámicamente a un `FlowLayoutPanel`. En ese mismo `UserControl` tengo un botón para eliminarse así mismo si el usuario lo desea, obviamente en tiempo de ejecución. Necesito eliminarlo desde el `Form`. Probé con esto pero no pasó nada porque el "Children" no me lo reconoce:

```
((FlowLayoutPanel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mejor respuesta y que me sirvio me la dieron en StackOverflow en ingles. Como no esta duplicada en español la dejo y no elimino la pregunta. Gracias a todos!

[Clik aqui para ir a la respuesta de la misma pregunta de este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868816/9944292)

Answer (score 2):

Hola buenas te dejo un ejemplo funcionando. En el evento click del botón que tienes en tu `UserControl` tenemos:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
    }
```

**EDITADO**

En el `Form` original deberias introducir esto:

```
 this.userControl11.Parent = this;
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: esto removerá al padre pero no al control en si... no provoca esto problemas ? 
de hecho no provoca problemas que un invocador se elimine así mismo ?

Comment: Gerardo, gracias por responder, lamentablemente no sirve eso, lanza el siguiente error:
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'"

Comment: @Mike No provoca ningun error, es el padre el que elimina al hijo.

Comment: @yerald Debes decirle en el editor al `userControl` quien es su padre. Añado el código a la respuesta,